# Comparison between DoubleRounder and BigDecimal RoundingMode

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I want to know if there is any advantage of using *BigDecimal RoundingMode* method over *DoubleRounder.round()*.

Also I observe the differences in the result when I try to use the same precision in two methods. For Example :

Using DoubleRounder.round()

```
System.out.println(""+DoubleRounder.round(0.0897435897435897, 5));  //gives 0.08974
```

Using BigDecimal RoundingMode

```
BigDecimal b= new BigDecimal(0.0897435897435897);

System.out.println(""+b.round(new MathContext(5,RoundingMode.CEILING)); //gives 0.089744
```

I see that there are 6 digits in decimal places while using BigDecimal instead of 5. Can anyone explain me why this is happening. And in  case I want to have exact 5 digit after decimal using BigDecimal, how do I need to modify this part of code?

Answer (score 1):

MathContext accept **precision**, it means starts from the leftmost nonzero digit.

you can use `bigDecimal.setScale(5, RoundingMode.CEILING)`.
**scale** is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.

e.g.
`System.out.println(b.setScale(5, RoundingMode.CEILING)); // gives you 0.08975`

Answer (score 0):

**It will give you 5 digit**

```
System.out.println(""+b.round(new MathContext(4,RoundingMode.CEILING))); //gives 0.08975
```